# Limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{n}{4} \int_0^{1/n}\left(\pi^{\sin^2x}+e^{\sin^2x}\right)^2\cos2x~dx \right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Are these statements about the following limits true?

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{n}{4} \int_0^{1/n}\left(\pi^{\sin^2x}+e^{\sin^2x}\right)^2\cos2x~dx \right) \stackrel{?}{=} 1, $$

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{n}{8} \int_{-1/n}^{1/n}\left(\pi^{\sin^2x}+e^{\sin^2x}\right)^2\cos2x~dx \right) \stackrel{?}{=} 1.
$$

Comment: The second of the two is kind of obvious given the first, since the function is obviously even.

Comment: Given any function $f$ continuous at some neighborhood of $x = 0$. By fundamental theorem of calculus $\lim_{n\to\infty} n \int_0^{1/n} f(x) dx = f(0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generally.** If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function then
$$
\int_0^{1/n}f(t)dt\sim \frac{f(0)}{n}.
$$
Indeed, if $~\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$, then it is easy to prove that $F'(0)=f(0)$. we just write
$$\left\vert\frac{F(x)}{x}-f(0)\right\vert\leq \int_0^1\left\vert f(tx)-f(0)\right\vert dt
$$
So, the  the continuity of $f$ at $0$ proves 
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{F(x)}{x}=f(0)
$$
Now, taking $x=1/n$ we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}nF\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0).
$$
applying, this to $f(x)=(\pi^{\sin^2 x}+e^{\sin^2x})^2\cos (2x)$ the desired conclusion follows because $f(0)=4$.

Comment: I didn't know that. Nice approach. Thank you, after that my observation is kind of triviality.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the answer is $1$.

One way to do it is to change the variable $y=nx$, then
$$
I_n=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \Big(\pi^{\sin^2(y/n)}+e^{\sin^2(y/n)}\Big)^2 \cos\left(\frac{2y}{n}\right)\,dy=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 f_n(y)\,dy.
$$
But the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $4$, as $n\to\infty$, and hence
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 f_n(y)\,dy\to \frac{1}{4}\cdot 4=1.
$$

Comment: Nice proof. Thank you.